# What are the requirements for a python package to be added to the conda (default channel) package list?

Tags: python, anaconda, package, conda

The docs make it clear that in order to add a package to the default channel an issue has to be raised (https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs/).

But what exactly are the requirements in terms of popularity, stability, security, etc. for a package to be considered for addition?

Comment: Bit evading your question, but maybe also useful information for some readers: if you want to have a widely available conda package, the easiest route in my opinion is contributing it to conda-forge. https://conda-forge.org/

Comment: True, and conda-forge is open to everyone willing to put in the work I understand. Still, I'm curious what makes a package important (?) enough to be added to the main package channel. It seems opaque, although I might just have missed something.

Comment: Since they don't seem to document a guideline, it would likely be better to ask the staff more directly: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues